# When I click on a link in my webview that points to a file, nothing happens

Tags: android, webview

I've created a webView in my app to view a website. When it comes to browsing webpages, it works just fine. But when I click on a file link(in my webview) that points to file stored on some server e.g. http://www.sgbau.ac.in/revised-engg-tech-w-2014.pdf , it does nothing.

What I intend it to do is download that file (regardless of its extension) into a folder named
"XYZ" on storage.

Here's the code I've tried (in my Java file):

```
package com.example.jdiet;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.content.res.Configuration;  
import android.view.KeyEvent;  
import android.view.Menu;  
import android.webkit.WebView;  
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;  
public class Sessional extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sessional);
    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getProgress();
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.sgbau.ac.in");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sessional, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
    {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have permission to access local memory?

Comment: What do you want to do? Download a file? In that case you should write your own code in the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method when the url matches the pdf extension and open another app with an intent or something. But I don't know what you want to do exactly. EDIT: a webview can't download files by itself. So override this method and create an AsyncTask to download the file.

Comment: @erad : Yeah . . I added the <android:uses-permission="WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"> tag in the manifest .

Comment: Do you have read as well?

Comment: @CaptainTeemo : I want to download file regardless of its extension ! Could you point me to some example that will elaborate things to me .

Comment: Also, so looking at your code, it looks like right now you hardcode a URI to a website on the Web. How are you implementing reading from a local file?

Comment: @user301915 regardless of its extension... ok, can you match some pattern instead?

Comment: @user301915 see my update to the answer for info about saving any file.

Comment: @user301915 probably you are also receiving some error, you can override also this method in your MyWebClient `onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)` Check it in the doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html

Comment: @erad : I don't intend my app to read local files . All it's gonna do is download Files from my server . Then users are supposed to read them using third party apps .

Comment: @CaptainTeemo : No error yet ! But thanks for the heads-up .

Comment: @user301915 Oh sorry. Misread. It's 5am over here haha. Have you tried looking at my updated answer below? It should give you some help as far as downloading files is concerned.

Comment: Thanx guys . Problemo solved . But I am also going to annoy you guys with more stupid questions . So keep an eye out for questions about Android and questions with poor grammatical structure ! :) :P

Answer (score 0):

To download a file, you can look at the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html).

> The following method extracts the file name from a URL and creates a file with that name in your app's internal cache directory:

```
public File getTempFile(Context context, String url) {
    File file;
    try {
        String fileName = Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment();
        file = File.createTempFile(fileName, null, context.getCacheDir());
    catch (IOException e) {
        // Error while creating file
    }
    return file;
}
```

> If you want to save public files on the external storage, use the getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() method to get a File representing the appropriate directory on the external storage. The method takes an argument specifying the type of file you want to save so that they can be logically organized with other public files, such as DIRECTORY_MUSIC or DIRECTORY_PICTURES. For example:

```
public File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) {
    // Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory. 
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
    if (!file.mkdirs()) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Directory not created");
    }
    return file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable the DownloadMangager in webview.

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
            String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
            long contentLength) {
      Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
      startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

and the browser looks after the downloading.